# Popup does not show when the button is clicked second time in Oracle ADF

Tags: oracle-adf

When clicking on a button for the first time the popup is showing up, but from the second click onwards, the popup doesn't show up.

```
<af:popup id="p1" contentDelivery="lazyUncached" autoCancel="diabled">
  <af:dialog type="yesNo" title="" dialogListner="pageflowScope.testBean.popupListner>
    <af:panelGroupLayout id="pg15" layout="scroll">
    <af:panelGroupLayout id="pg15" layout="vertical">
       <af:outputText value="Do you want to save the document?" id="ot2">
    </af:panelGroupLayout>
    </af:panelGroupLayout>
  </af:dialog>
</af:popup>
```

```
public void saveActionListner(ActionEvent actionEvent){
   RichPopup popup = (RichPopup) JSFUtils.findComponentInRoot("p1");
   popup.show(new RichPopup.popupHints);
```

```
<af:commandButton text="save" id="cb1" actionListner="#{pageflowScope.testBean.saveActionListner} action="#{pageflowScope.testBean.outcome}" partialTriggers="#{pageflowScope.testBean.updatedStatus}" partialSubmit="true">
  </af:commandButton>
```

Comment: Can you tell us your exact JDev version, please?

How do you close the popup?

Is the popup on a jsff fragment or a jsf page or a jspx page?

Comment: Hi Timo, thank you for your quick response! The JDev version is 12.2.1.4.0. I'm closing the popup when the user clicks on yes button on the popup, I'm using dialogListner and saving data to db. The popup is on a jsff fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you use an actionListerner and an action on the command button? The actionListener should be enough.

It doesn't make sense to show a popup and navigate away directly afterward. Remove the action from the button and see if this fixes the problem.

If you still have the same problem, check the log files for any errors. You should look into the browser console too and check for JavaScript errors there.

Comment: Thank you ever so much Timo!! The issue is resolved once I've removed the action attribute from the commandButton. :)